liquibase with mariadb (memsql and java)
trying to run this script:
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$( docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Status}}' iam_db )" == "exited" ]; then
  echo db is down, starting db...
  docker start iam_db
  sleep 10
fi
echo migrating db... If it fails after recreating, please wait for about 1 minute before rerunning
set -o xtrace
liquibase --defaultsFile iam/db/liquibase/liquibase.properties --url jdbc:mariadb://${MEMSQL_HOST}:3306/${MEMSQL_IAM_DB}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true --username=${MEMSQL_USER:-root} --password=${MEMSQL_PASSWORD:-123456} --classpath $MARIADB_CONNECTOR_LOCATION --logLevel severe migrate
set +o xtrace

and got error i cant resolve any way i tried:
ERROR: Exception Details
ERROR: Exception Primary Class:  SQLException
ERROR: Exception Primary Reason:  RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile not set)
ERROR: Exception Primary Source:  4.27.0
[2024-05-14 21:16:46] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iam_ingestion?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile not set)
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/iam_ingestion?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile not set)

change all version of mariadb, java, liquibase
try to change url to: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
nothing..

the error tells you that the mariadb server has the correct encrytion

This looks like an error from MySQL (and not MariaDB). While MariaDB connector can work, it is just passing on the error. allowPublicKeyRetrieval=True in connection url maybe.
